# Using Typescript Definitions Files from Definitely Typed with Older Version of Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, version, typescript-typings

I've been working on a project using Typescript 1.8.10 with React and Redux. I've been trying to incorporate a couple of third party React component libraries, like [React Date Picker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker), but I keep running into the issue that the typings files on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/react-datepicker/index.d.ts) are created for Typescript 2.1. I would expect there to be a 1.8 branch, but I have yet to find one. Does anyone know where to find older typings files that work with TS 1.8? Do they even exist? Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript 1.8.10 has been released in [April/2016](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v1.8.10), so I think this commit history on DefinitelyTyped will work to you: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/e14d135afb675ddb135eb43d5c70f1d86d8a244a/react-datepicker

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great, let me create an answer, so you can mark as correct and anybody else can use the same solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 1.8.10 has been released in [April/2016](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v1.8.10). You can look inside the "DefinitelyTyped [commit history](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master)" to get the snapshot for this period.

For example, this commit on DefinitelyTyped will work to you:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/e14d135afb675ddb135eb43d5c70f1d86d8a244a/react-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:
"The @types publisher tool actually tags releases based on compatibility.

To be able to install declaration files that are compatible with TypeScript 2.2, you can write

```
npm install @types/body-parser@ts2.2
```

It's not always perfect, but it'll usually get the job done."

[From this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934668/how-can-i-install-types-compatible-with-an-older-version-of-typescript)