# How can I install @types compatible with an older version of TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm, types, definitelytyped, declaration-files

My project uses package like `@types/express` and `@types/body-parser`. Recently these `.d.ts` files were updated to use generic defaults, but that means these declaration files now require TypeScript 2.3 or above.

However, my project still uses an older version of TypeScript - TypeScript 2.2. How do I use npm to make sure my project can still understand these definition files without upgrading?

Answer (score 6):

The `@types` publisher tool actually tags releases based on compatibility.

To be able to install declaration files that are compatible with TypeScript 2.2, you can write

```
npm install @types/body-parser@ts2.2
```

It's not always perfect, but it'll usually get the job done.